# Make UIButton Stay Attached to Footer During Rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uibutton

I want my UIButton to always stay on bottom of screen without adjusting the X all the time. Here is my code that hides my button in horizontal mode.

```
    UIImage *greenBtnImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green-btn-iphone.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bt setBackgroundImage:greenBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bt.frame = CGRectMake(14.0f,406.0f,292.0f,41.0f);
    [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(didClickButton:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bt setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bt.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

    bt.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:bt];
```

I have trouble finding answer how to do it programmatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, this should help:

```
bt.autorezisingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Disclaimer: I never did that myself programmatically so far, used autorezising only in conjunction with the Interface Builder.